# Permission command not working in ubuntu during deployment stage

Tags: linux, deployment, permissions, chmod, aws-codebuild

I am Using AWS codepipeline for deployment of my app.During codedeploy stage there is an after_install.sh script which runs command inside the server. I have added below command

```
sudo chown ubuntu:www-data -R $basePath/backend
cd $basePath/backend
sudo chmod -R 0777 storage/
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan optimize
composer dump-autoload
sudo chmod -R 0777 storage/
```

Rest all command works, but issue is that the chmod command doesnot recursively changes permissions, each time I have to go manually inside the server and hit the command.I troubleshooted it but I am unable to find and fix for it.

Comment: storage/ doesn't look right. IT doesn't look like a full path?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Inside Storage directory there are other files and folders also. I have given them permissions recursively